# Unitary dual of $\mathrm{Sp}_4(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: representation-theory

We know the unitary dual of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, unitary dual of $SU(2,2)$, how about $\mathrm{Sp}_4(\mathbb{R})$? Is there any known result? If so, can anyone provide me any references? Thanks!